# Javascript - function doesn't get external input values from JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, server

I have the following function stored in my `sdk.php` file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function saveObject(params) {
    console.log('p: ' + params);
}
</script>
```

In another php file - `index.php` - I call that function passing input values as parameters:

```
Text: <input type="text" name="aText" id="aText"><br>
Number: <input type="number" name="aNumber" id="aNumber"><br>
<script>
// Save object
var params = [
    'tableName=' + 'Test',
    '&ST_text=' + $('#aText').val(),
    '&NU_likes=' + $('#aNumber').val(),     
].toString().replace(/,/g, '');
</script>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="#" onclick="saveObject(params)">Save Object</a>
```

Now, if I type something in the 2 input files and hit the **Save Object** button, this is what I get in the Chrome console:

```
p: tableName=Test&ST_text=&NU_likes=
```

Why am I not getting the `aText` and `aNumber` values in the string I compose?

I'm asking this because if I move the params array into the `saveObject()` function, I get the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do realise that Javascript does not run in .php files?? It only runs once that js code gets to the browser

Comment: That script that composes the `params` is only ran once, on page load.  It is not rebuilding any time the user changes one of the input values.  For that, you would need a change handler for the inputs.  Otherwise, forego the change handler and just compose the `params` object inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your params are not being defined because the script is only executed on page load. You need to define the values after an event, like clicking the Save Object button. 
Try something like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" id="saveButton" href="#">Save Object</a>
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#saveButton").click(function () {
var params = [//define params here];
saveObject(params);
});
```